# how to echo javascript generated value in href?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my javascript code below (Just to get current url)

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction();">

<p id="myurl"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myurl").innerHTML =
    window.location.host;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And Now i want to use `<p id="myurl"></p>` as below:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<p id="demo"></p>">Share on Facebook</a> <br>
```

But as it cant be execured inside href="value"

Is there any way to do that with php or something else?

Comment: in u= param you must pass only URL it will not accept any tag

Comment: is there any other method?

Comment: why you want to pass <p> tag??

Comment: i want to get current url of page

Comment: What exactly you want? Why you place tag instead of value in get method? Please clear your need first..

Comment: use <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pure javascript (default url in href):

```
<a id="share_url" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=">Share on Facebook</a>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var el = document.getElementById("share_url");
        el.href += window.location.host;
    }
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrkjr23o/1/

Other way to create *href* attribute dynamically:

```
<a id="share_url">Share on Facebook</a>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var el = document.getElementById("share_url");
        el.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=';
        el.href += window.location.host;
    }
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrkjr23o/

Answer (score 2):

Use this :-

```
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">Share on Facebook</a> <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming client only solution is needed here, server can be anything (PHP, ASP, etc.)
All you've to do is to modify the href property of anchor tag. You can modify your code as -

```
var elm = document.getElementById("demo");
var URLBase = elm.getAttribute("href");
var fullURL = URLBase.window.location.host;
elm.setAttribute("href", fullURL);
```